# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n)=0$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n=L$ imply $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \exp(a_n)*c_n-L*\exp(-b_n)=0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider the sequences $\{a_n\}_{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}}<0$, $\{b_n\}_{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}}>0$, $\{c_n\}_{\forall n \in \mathbb{N}}>0$ and suppose
$$
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n)=0\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} c_n=L<\infty
\end{cases}
$$

Could you help me to show that
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\exp(a_n)*c_n-L*\exp(-b_n)]=0
$$
?

---

I know that by assumption
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} [\exp(a_n)*c_n-L*\exp(-b_n)]= \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}  [\exp(-b_n+o(1))*(L+o(1))-L*\exp(-b_n)]
$$
where $o(1)$ is a number going to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$. How can I proceed from here?

---

Let me add another assumption (thanks to a comment below)
$$
\exp(a_n)\equiv \Pi_{k=1}^{2n} x_{n,k}
$$
where $x_{n,k}\in [0,1]$ and $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} x_{n,k}=1$ $\forall k$

Comment: Do we have any assumption on $\{a_n\}$ other than negative ? is it increasing (so it has a limit) ? If $\{a_n\}$ has a limit, you just need to factorize by $\exp(a_n)$ and you're done

Comment: I have that $a_n\equiv \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^{2n} n \log(x_{k,n})$ so that $\exp(a_n)=\Pi_{k=1}^{2n}x_{k,n}$. Moreover, $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}x_{k,n}=1$ and $x_{k,n}\in (0,1)$  $\forall k$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just compute
$$ |e^{a_n}c_n - L e^{-b_n}| = e^{a_n}|c_n - L e^{-(a_n+b_n)}| \leq |c_n - L e^{-(a_n+b_n)}|. $$
Now $c_n\to L$ and $a_n+b_n\to 0$. So, because $e^x$ and $|x|$ are continuous functions, you can "pass to the limit inside the functions" and get
$$ |e^{a_n}c_n - L e^{-b_n}| \leq |c_n - L e^{-(a_n+b_n)}| \to |L-Le^{-0}| = 0. $$
By the comparison principle, you get convergence of that guy to 0.

Answer (score 1):

In these kind of problems,
I try to get the
terms that go to zero
by themselves.
As long as the other terms
behave 
(usually meaning that
they are bounded),
the rest usually follows.

$\begin{array}\\
\exp(a_n)*c_n-L*\exp(-b_n)
&=\exp(a_n)*(c_n-L+L)-L*\exp(-a_n-b_n+a_n)\\
&=\exp(a_n)*(c_n-L)+\exp(a_n)L-L*\exp(-a_n-b_n)\exp(a_n)\\
&=\exp(a_n)*(c_n-L)+L\exp(a_n)\left(1-\exp(-a_n-b_n)\right)\\
\end{array}
$

Combine this with
your assumptions that
$c_n-L \to 0$
and
$a_n+b_n \to 0$
and you are done.

Comment: But one has zero assumptions on $\exp{a_n}$ on its convergence, so can't conclude from it.